# How to support retina in a CALayer based NPAPI plugin?

Tags: safari, calayer, npapi

I'm writing a Safari NPAPI plugin using CoreAnimationDrawingModel. This lets me create high performance CAOpenGLLayer and return it to the browser (I'm using this: https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI:CoreAnimationDrawingModel).

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble supporting Retina displays in this setup because I cannot find a way of working out whether or not the plugin is hosted on a Retina display. Without this information I cannot set the CALayer's contentScale property properly.

In native applications I'd host the CALayer in an NSView and watch viewDidChangeBackingProperties to obtain the required resolution information. I'm not sure whether there is a way of obtaining the layer host in the NPAPI world? Even if that was possible, I'd be annoying to have to poll it for the resolution, ideally I'd want to register some kind of a notification listener.

I'm writing my plugin using FireBreath (http://www.firebreath.org/) and talked with the devs there (Richard Bateman) on IRC, but they suggested asking here (Stuart Morgan was mentioned as a good person to ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [a spec](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI%3aContentsScaleFactor) for passing this information to NPAPI plugins. I'm not completely sure of the implementation status; Chrome doesn't implement it, casual inspection of Firefox source suggests it does, and since it was authored by an Apple engineer it's likely that Safari does.

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly helpful. I'll test this in detail early next week.

The spec suggests that the browser will keep sending update notifications (with NPP_SetValue). I haven't seen those in my tests so far, but maybe they'll only start _after_ NPN_GetValue query.

Comment: For other people interested in this, I now added relevant support code to FireBreath plugin framework, atm it's awaiting merge: https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/pull/119. It works well with at least Safari 6.0.5.

Comment: This the only useful piece of information I could find about retina support in Safari NPAPI plugins. I have a Core Graphics plug-in and I couldn't find how to make it work with retina. Any thoughts?

Comment: That's addressed in the linked document: "For Core Graphics plug-ins, the CGContext sent along with the NPCocoaEventDrawRect will already be scaled, so plug-ins using simple drawing will work without modifications. If a plug-in draws images or uses a backing buffer, the buffer size in pixels should be scaled appropriately using the contents scale factor."